# Total payment and total value becomes zero when user clicked OK (I pass the string to another form)

Tags: vb.net

This is the FORMPRECEIPT CODE

```
Public Class Formpreceipt 
Public Property amountpass As String
Dim partyy As Double 
Dim bdayy As Double 
Dim vipp As Double
 Dim deluxee As Double 
Dim friess As Double 
Dim burgerr As Double 
Dim cupcakee As Double 
Dim pizzaa As Double 
Dim icedteaa As Double 
Dim sodaa As Double 
Dim sojuu As Double 
Dim beerr As Double 
Private Sub Formpreceipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load lbltotal.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#100F0E") 
lblchange.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#100F0E") 
lblpayment.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#100F0E") 
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnplaceorder.Click
    partyy = Formrooms.txtparty.Text * 200
    bdayy = Formrooms.txtbday.Text * 300
    vipp = Formrooms.txtvip.Text * 400
    deluxee = Formrooms.txtdeluxe.Text * 500
    friess = Formsnacks.txtfries.Text * 40
    burgerr = Formsnacks.txtburger.Text * 80
    cupcakee = Formsnacks.txtcupcake.Text * 35
    pizzaa = Formsnacks.txtpizza.Text * 150
    icedteaa = Formdrinks.txticedtea.Text * 20
    sodaa = Formdrinks.txtsoda.Text * 35
    sojuu = Formdrinks.txtsoju.Text * 80
    beerr = Formdrinks.txtbeer.Text * 100






    lbltotal.Text = "₱" & Format(partyy + bdayy + vipp + deluxee + friess + burgerr + cupcakee + pizzaa + icedteaa + sodaa + sojuu + beerr)
    lblpayment.Text = "P" & Format(amountpass)
End Sub
Private Sub btninputpayment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btninputpayment.Click
    Forminput.Show()
End Sub
```

This is the form input amount code.

```
Public Class Forminput Private Sub txtinputamnt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtinputamnt.TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub Form6_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtinputamnt.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#100F0E")
End Sub

Private Sub txtinputamnt_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtinputamnt.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnback_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnback.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click
    Dim obj As New Formpreceipt
    obj.amountpass = txtinputamnt.Text
    obj.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```

I expect that when the user input an amount and then clicked OK. The user payment will have the amount that the user input. But in this case when the user clicked ok, the total amount and the total payment will reset to 0, and then when the user click again the place order. The total amount and the total payment will display. (for example, the user have 300 peso bill (total amount), and the user input a 500 peso (total payment) . When the user clicked ok, the total amount and the total payment becomes 0. When the user clicked again the place order button, then the total amount and the total payment will be display)
[image: This is when the user clicked place order for tota]
![[image: This is where the user will input an amount]]
[image: This is where the user inputted an amount and clicked ok button]

Comment: Setting amountpass doesn't automatically update  lblpayment.Text, you need to either call the Formreceip.Button1_Click or use properties where setting value can trigger another action.

Comment: I will try this sir thankyou

Comment: still having the same error bro

Comment: It looks to me like `Formpreceipt` opens up a `Forminput`? Then after an input is made you want to return to `Formpreceipt`. If that is the case, you should NOT be making a new receipt form. Show us the code that opens up `Forminput` and we can help you fix this issue.

Comment: can i paste here the code @Idle_Mind

Comment: EDIT your question above to show what is happening.

Comment: I already edited it @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`.  This will make code in your receipt form STOP until the the input dialog is dismissed.  Once code returns you can update the form:

```
Private Sub btninputpayment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btninputpayment.Click
    If Forminput.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' ... do something with Forminput.Amount ....
        amountpass = Forminput.Amount
        lblpayment.Text = "P" & Format(amountpass)
    End If
End Sub
```

In Forminput, you'd do something like:

```
Public Class Forminput

    Public Amount As String

    Private Sub txtinputamnt_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtinputamnt.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnback_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnback.Click
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnok.Click
        Me.Amount = txtinputamnt.Text
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

End Class
```